# None of the values in my data are within the confidence interval

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am doing a Wilcoxon test in R and one thing that has surprise me is that when I compute the confidence interval for the below mentioned dataset I get a 95% confidence interval of (-807,198), and non of the values for the treated and untreated groups are within that interval.

For example:

```
treated <- c(323,421,578,300,256,640,912,370)
untreated <- c(2388,210,380,345,1130,260,665,1157)

wilcox.test(treated,untreated,conf.int=TRUE)
```

This is the output of the test with the 95% confidence interval

> ```
>     Wilcoxon rank sum test
> data:  treated and untreated
> W = 25, p-value = 0.5054
> alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>    -807  198
> sample estimates:
> difference in location 
>              -83.5
> ```

Can anyone help me solving or understanding this issue?

Comment: Notice the test is highly non-significant

Comment: Thanks, I have notice that, but  as the confidence interval is computed from the data shouldn't it cover my values?

Comment: It's the confidence interval for the location shift, not for the distribution of your data.

Comment: How did you compute C.I. values  and  difference in location ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the help page,

```
conf.int    = a confidence interval for the location parameter.
estimate    = an estimate of the location parameter.
```

Now, the value of `estimate` is -83.5, i.e. the difference in location.

Thus, I deduce that the confidence interval is actually a confidence interval for the difference in location.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Ocram's answer (which is correct + 1), suppose you subtracted 500 from all the values:

```
t2 <- treated - 500
u2 <- untreated - 500
```

then did the same test:

```
wilcox.test(t2, u2, conf.int=TRUE)
```

you get the same result as with your original. What matters is the shift in location between treated and untreated, not the actual location.